# Error fetching notes: TypeError: Note.find is not a function

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongoose

I'm building a simple note-taking React and NodeJS app, and have a NoteList component that's supposed to get all the existing notes from my MongoDB database but it's not showing anything. In the browser console, this is the error I get:

```
Error fetching notes: TypeError: Note.find is not a function
    at getNotes (db.js:28:1)
    at fetchNotes (bundle.js:793:84)
    at bundle.js:803:5
    at MainPage.js:19:1
    at App.js:25:1
```

This is my db.js file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const noteSchema = new Schema({
  address: String,
  title: String,
  content: String,
  citation: String,
}, {
  collection: 'notes' 
});

const Note = mongoose.model('Note', noteSchema);

// Get all notes
async function getNotes() {
  return Note.find({});
}

// Also, the rest of the other functions here...

module.exports = {
  Note: Note,
  createNote,
  getNoteById,
  getNotes,
  updateNote,
  deleteNote
};
```

I have checked for typos, incorrect paths, incorrect imports and can't find any errors. I've also checked all my routes using REST Client and everything is working perfectly.

Comment: I would like to see when and where you call `getNotes`.